# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript code and html code are.When I try to run the code its shows the InvalidValueError in chrome.

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
   function intilize() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("textarea"));

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var location = "Address: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
    location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.A + "<br/>";
    location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.F;

    });

};
```

HTML CODE:`

```
             <div class="input-group" id="search">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" 
             id="textarea" placeholder="Search for Location...">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>



         </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: could you post your console error.

Comment: js?key=AIzaSyDFiYTIGfRQUuDzEG5q1oufNVZaRwZLg_k&libraries=places:35 InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement